# 7. Пользователь вводит три числа. Найти сумму тех чисел, которые делятся на 5. Если таких чисел нет, то вывести error

Tags: python

```
import math
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
s = a + b + c
if a % 5 == 0 or b % 5 == 0 or c % 5 == 0:
    print(s)
```

Недавно начала питон изучать, не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы код выдавал только сумму чисел, которые делятся на 5 :(

Comment: поменяйте 'or' на 'and'

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов имеется в виду, что нужно выбрать только те числа, которые будут делиться на 5, и из них составить сумму.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_ = map(int, input().split())


list_ = list(filter(lambda element: not (element % 5), list_))


print(sum(list_))
```

Comment: `print(sum(filter(lambda x: not(x % 5), map(int, input().split()))))`

Comment: Да, оба преобразования в `list` тут не нужны.

Comment: Почитайте Дзен Питона, господа) "Простое лучше сложного".

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/vKUT3V

```
print(sum(x for x in map(int, input().split()) if x%5==0))
```

```
5 7 10
```

```
15
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно с использованием for i написать, если уже проходили.

```
a, b, c = [int(input()) for i in range(3)]
numbers = [a, b, c]
result = 0
for i in numbers:
    if i % 5 == 0:
        result += i
print(result)
```

А если еще не проходили for i, а только на блоке if,elif,else
тогда перебором

```
a, b, c = [int(input()) for i in range(3)]

if a % 5 == 0 and b % 5 == 0 and c % 5 == 0:
    print(a + c + b)
elif a % 5 == 0 and b % 5 == 0 and c % 5 != 0:
    print(a + b)
elif a % 5 == 0 and b % 5 != 0 and c % 5 == 0:
    print(a + c)
elif a % 5 != 0 and b % 5 == 0 and c % 5 == 0:
    print(b + c)
```

Comment: Какой-то непитонный способ)

Comment: Почему же? ) очень даже питонный на базовом уровне, сам такие задачки решал в самом начале именно методом перебора if,elif,else и тонной инпутов. При базовом обучении, эти задачки помогают запомнить структуру ввода ))

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 0
if a % 5 == 0:
    s += a
if b % 5 == 0:
    s += b
if c % 5 == 0:
    s += c
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сначала занести все числа в список, а затем отфильтровать его при помощи [`filter()`](https://pythonru.com/uroki/funkcija-filter-dlja-nachinajushhih). В качестве функции может быть либо пользовательская, либо [лямбда-функция](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/10_useful_functions/lambda.html). Я же запишу оба примера ниже:

```py
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
# 4 10 9 55 8 -5

# Способ 1 (через пользовательскую функцию)

def filter_func(x):
  return x % 5 == 0
  
first = list(filter(filter_func, lst))
print(first)
# [10, 55, -5]

# Способ 2 (через лямбда-функцию)

second = list(filter(lambda x: x % 5 == 0, lst))
print(second)
# [10, 55, -5]
```

Найти сумму из элементов списка можно либо вручную через цикл, либо через функцию-сумматор [sum()](https://pythonz.net/references/named/sum/).